# How do I retrieve the Rails cache-busting timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to Rails, so please .. be gentle. :)

There's apparently a cache-busting timestamp that gets appended as a querystring to JavaScript and CSS includes in Rails.  How can I obtain that value programmatically?  (I'd like to be able to use it for other purposes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.  If you deploy with Capistrano, one thing you can do is to set `ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID']` of the version number contained in REVISION.

Answer (score 2):

It's the last modified timestamp of the file in question. Rails calculates it in `ActionView`'s `asset_tag_helper.rb` as follows, but the important part is `File.mtime(path).to_i`

```
    # Use the RAILS_ASSET_ID environment variable or the source's
    # modification time as its cache-busting asset id.
    def rails_asset_id(source)
      if asset_id = ENV["RAILS_ASSET_ID"]
        asset_id
      else
        if @@cache_asset_timestamps && (asset_id = @@asset_timestamps_cache[source])
          asset_id
        else
          path = File.join(ASSETS_DIR, source)
          asset_id = File.exist?(path) ? File.mtime(path).to_i.to_s : ''

          if @@cache_asset_timestamps
            @@asset_timestamps_cache_guard.synchronize do
              @@asset_timestamps_cache[source] = asset_id
            end
          end

          asset_id
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Ah, ok -- I think I misinterpreted the meaning of that timestamp, then; I was under the impression it applied to the app as a whole, rather than the file it's attached to.  What I really want to know is the "last started" time of the Rails app (or some other equivalent identifier), which I'd like to use programmatically somehow.  Does Rails provide such a facility?  In a half-hour or so digging around online, it doesn't appear to.

Comment: No, the main reason being that "last started" isn't a strictly defined timestamp. If you are running a server using Passenger, then Rails will be starting and stopping instances constantly to manage your resources properly. If you can be a bit more specific about what you need then there may be a better solution

Comment: Ok, sure.  Basically, I've got a heavily browser-cached app that needs to know when a new version's been deployed.  Rather than polling for a manually assigned version ID, I'd prefer to write an automatically assigned version ID (so I don't have to remember to assign it) to a DOM node in fresh pages, then have the JavaScript code check that value to decide whether to prompt for reload.  Seems like there has to be a standard way to do this, but I don't really know where to look.  Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

As I posted, it's easy if youj deploy with Capistrano as the REVISION file contains a unique hash id, but you could also create your own version id and assign it to RAILS_ASSET_ID.